# Open VSIX Gallery, customizing page

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Just uploaded an extension to the Open VSIX Gallery.

http://vsixgallery.com/extension/Snippeter.205e93a2-67fd-418d-a773-558dbce0ffd0/

I would like to modify the page at the Open VSIX Gallery to add a link to the source code in github but, turns out, I am too daft to figure out how to do it.

https://github.com/LaraSQP/Snippeter

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, or part of it, is to modify the `source.extension.vsixmanifest` file.

Comment: Hi Lara, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer),it just a reminder :)

Comment: It was also necessary to create an account with AppVeyor. Whoever might be interested should look at my repo above and the file `appveyor.yml`.